# Using Docker image from Github registry is unauthorized

Tags: docker, github-actions

- I created Docker image locally
- Tagged it for Github Docker registry
- Pushed it to Github Docker registry

Now I want to use it in Github action that create Docker image in `FROM` field but it always fails with `unauthorized` error - why ?

here are the steps:

```
docker tag my_image:1.0 ghcr.io/<github_user>/<organization>/<repo_name>/my_image:1.0

docker push ghcr.io/<github_user>/<organization>/<repo_name>/my_image:1.0
a4f566342e89: Pushed
0378d9143186: Pushed
...
f337026e7d90: Pushed
```

everything as you see completes successfully and I can even `docker pull` it on my computer

then I setup Github action and set it to start Powershell script that create Docker image from this Dockerfile:

So Github action set as:

```
...
...
jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: windows-2019

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Package with Docker and push to Github packages
      id: build_and_push_docker_image    
      env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}    
      run: |
        src/database/base-image/github-build.ps1
```

There just 1 step !

and Powershell script itself do:

```
...
docker login ghcr.io --username $env:GITHUB_ACTOR --password $env:GITHUB_TOKEN
...
docker build src/database/base-image --file "src/database/base-image/databaseCreateBaseImage.Dockerfile" --tag sqldatabase/base:$VERSION
...
...
```

and Docker file is:

```
FROM ghcr.io/<github_user>/<organization>/<repo_name>/my_image:1.0

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

...
...
```

but sadly when Github action runs it always fails on line `FROM` with error message:

```
Step 1/7 : FROM ghcr.io/<github_user>/<organization>/<repo_name>/my_image:1.0
Get https://ghcr.io/v2/<github_user>/<organization>/<repo_name>/my_image/manifests/1.0: unauthorized
...
...
```

May be someone could shed some light - why it is not authorized to `pull` this image ? Everything runs without error until this `FROM` line :(

Comment: I got similar issue to day, the solution is to go to package settings, and set the packagge visibility to public, because by default it is private, even your repo is public

Answer (score 14):

This helped me:

```
echo '<my_token>' | docker login ghcr.io -u <my_username> --password-stdin
```

*<my_token> is the PAT from Github*

Answer (score 6):

My mistake

According to Github documentation [Authenticating to GitHub Packages](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/about-github-packages#authenticating-to-github-packages) **using `GITHUB_TOKEN` is not (!) enough**. If you want to work with Github registry (ghcr.io) you **must (!)** use your Personal Access Token.

Comment: Yes, works with the manual https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/about-github-packages#authenticating-to-github-packages

Comment: or you could make the package public? https://niklasmtj.de/blog/gh-actions-workflows-combination-with-ghcr

Answer (score 4):

Make sure GitHub Actions can access the Docker Image (like [@sihil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3990127/sihil) mentioned) and add the following step to your job:

```
- name: Login to GitHub Container Registry
  uses: docker/login-action@v3
  with:
    registry: ghcr.io
    username: ${{ github.actor }}
    password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: docker/login-action@v2

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to do two things here:

- First of all, ensure that the Package settings (bottom right of the package page) allow access to actions running in the repository in question
- Secondly, ensure that you have added the package permission to your job

More details in my answer to [GITHUB_TOKEN permission denied write package when build and push docker in github workflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70646920)